# Trying to iterate in a list Python

Tags: python

I'm still trying to create a semi-random list of letter. I want my list to have 60 letters but exactly 20% of the time I want the same letter than 2 letters back..

I did this code :

```
import random
from random import shuffle
import pandas as pd

probab = range(61)

shuffle(probab)

letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']

my_list = [random.choice(letters) for _ in range(2)]

for i in probab.items():
    if i < 12:   # choice of number between
        my_list.append(my_list[len(my_list)-2])   # add the letter n-2

    else:
        my_list.append(random.choice(letters))

print(my_list).
```

The logic that I have we did problem is that I create a list from 1-60, then mixed it.

After I want to do a loop, the code look if the first item is smaller than 12, if yes then add the same letter than 2 back if not add a random letter...

I thought 12 because, its 20% of 60

I get this error when I run the code listed :

```
for i in probab.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can iterate over lists directly `for i in probab:`

Comment: dictionaries have `items` method. not list.

Comment: for exactly 20 %, take range(60). if np.random.rand()< 0.2 does the trick to.

Comment: I always get 18 times that it's the same letter... I tried what you said @PatrickHaugh and @ B.M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic needs a slight adjustment: if you want repeats 20% of the time then the other 80% of the time you have to make sure you *don't* get a repeat. The simple way to do that is with a loop. Alternatively, you could choose from a collection of letters that doesn't include the unwanted letter, but that's more verbose, and doing an extra loop or two when generating the random letter will probably be faster.

Also, since you want a list of 60 letters, `probab` has to be of length 58. And there's no need to make `letters` a list: `random.choice` will happily choose from a string.

```
from random import choice, shuffle 

num = 60

letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKL'
my_list = [choice(letters),  choice(letters)]
probab = list(range(num - 2))
shuffle(probab)

# We want 20% of the letters to repeat the letter 2 letters back
repeatnum = num * 20 // 100 
for i in probab:
    ch = prev = my_list[-2]
    if i >= repeatnum:
        while ch == prev:
            ch = choice(letters)
    my_list.append(ch)

# verify 
count = 0
for i in range(2, num):
    if my_list[i] == my_list[i - 2]:
        count += 1

print(''.join(my_list), len(my_list), count)
```

**typical output**

```
GBJEBKKKLKGJGKHIBLDKGKCKIKFCABDDBCKFJDEDJLAAADALEIIFICHHEGEG 60 12
```